# MKAnnotation just shown after move camera (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to use the `MapKit-Framework` in iOS. I have a map, where I draw a `polyline`.
Now I want to add some simple `annotations`. I add them to the map, but they are not shown directly. I have to move the camera. After I move the camera or use the zoom, the `annotations` are visible.
What I have to call to refresh the map to show the `annotations` directly?

```
var zugEndeAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation();
zugEndeAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: zugEnde.coordinate.latitude , longitude: zugEnde.coordinate.longitude);
self.map.addAnnotation(zugEndeAnnotation);
```

best regards

Comment: No one an idea? I change my code to custom annotations, but got the same problem.

Comment: Solved. I have to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { myfunc() }, cause i come from another thread.